# Expose service on k8 Infrastructure

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio, rancher, istio-gateway, hetzner-cloud

i applied this helm chart:

https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/magento2-helm

All the services are up and running. Now i decided to expose everything on 80 so i bought a cloud on hetzner and installed rancher+istio (master on rancher+ 1 worker node).

I'm still learning and reading all docs i thought to put a load balancer and target it to the worker node.
but i think i'm missing more configuration.

My idea was:
Call domain.com->Load Balancer-> Istio -> ServicePod -> Node

At the moment im having "503,No server is available to handle this request."

This is my virtual service:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
 annotations:
   meta.helm.sh/release-name: magento
   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: magento
 generation: 2
 labels:
   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
 name: mg-virtualservice
 namespace: magento
spec:
 gateways:
   - istio-gateway/istio-default-gateway
 hosts:
   - SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM
 http:
   - corsPolicy:
       allowHeaders:
         - authorization
         - content-type
       allowMethods:
         - POST
         - OPTIONS
         - GET
       allowOrigins:
         - regex: https://.*.DOMAIN.COM
     fault:
       abort:
         httpStatus: 503
         percentage: {}
     retries:
       attempts: 3
       retryOn: gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream,5xx
     route:
       - destination:
           host: varnish
           port:
             number: 80
     timeout: 30s
```

At the moment istio isn't loggin any request.
How can i manage this flow?

Thanks for help!